# how to change the text size dynamically in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have loaded the text in the ViewPager by loading them into a fragment. Inside the fragment, there is a WebView. which is written in View setFragmentView.

I need to change the size of the font dynamically.

so I have added a seek bar and on touching the seek to bar the size should change(for now).

but my currently loaded page does not change its font size.

the next page in the ViewPager is updated.

Is their a way to reload the whole fragment.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    changeFont("font/Raleway-Light.ttf");

    rlFontSettings = findViewById(R.id.rl_font_settings);
    rlFontSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    sbVolumeController = findViewById(R.id.sb_volume_controller);

    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    pxScreenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    sbVolumeController.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            Log.d("year", "onStartTrackingTouch: inside the seek 1 ");
            changedVolumeValue = 50;
            webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(changedVolumeValue);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        String filePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("filePath");
        isPickedWebView = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isWebView");

        try {
            reader = new Reader();

            //Setting optionals once per file is enough.
            reader.setMaxContentPerSection(1250);
            reader.setCssStatus(isPickedWebView ? CssStatus.INCLUDE : CssStatus.OMIT);
            reader.setIsIncludingTextContent(true);
            reader.setIsOmittingTitleTag(true);

            // This method must be called before readSection.
            reader.setFullContent(filePath);

//                int lastSavedPage = reader.setFullContentWithProgress(filePath);
            if (reader.isSavedProgressFound()) {
                int lastSavedPage = reader.loadProgress();
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(lastSavedPage);
            }

        } catch (ReadingException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}

@Override
public View onFragmentReady(int position) {

    BookSection bookSection = null;

    try {
        bookSection = reader.readSection(position);
    } catch (ReadingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (OutOfPagesException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.pageCount = e.getPageCount();

        if (isSkippedToPage) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Max page number is: " + this.pageCount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    isSkippedToPage = false;

    if (bookSection != null) {
        return setFragmentView(isPickedWebView, bookSection.getSectionContent(), "text/html", "UTF-8"); // reader.isContentStyled

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    fontSettings = menu.findItem(R.id.action_font);
    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    fontSettings.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            rlFontSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            if (query != null && !query.equals("")) {

                if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(query)) {
                    loseFocusOnSearchView();

                    int skippingPage = Integer.valueOf(query);

                    if (skippingPage >= 0) {
                        isSkippedToPage = true;
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(skippingPage);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Page number can't be less than 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } else {
                    loseFocusOnSearchView();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Only numbers are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
        loseFocusOnSearchView();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
        reader.saveProgress(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved page: " + mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ReadingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Progress is not saved: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (OutOfPagesException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Progress is not saved. Out of Bounds. Page Count: " + e.getPageCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private View setFragmentView(boolean isContentStyled, String data, String mimeType, String encoding) {

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    isReContentStyled = isContentStyled;
    reData = data;
    reMimeType =mimeType;
    reEncoding = encoding;


    if (isContentStyled) {

        webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        Log.d("year", "setFragmentView: mytest 1 "+changedVolumeValue);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(changedVolumeValue);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        Log.d("year", "setFragmentView: mytest 2 "+changedVolumeValue);

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, mimeType, encoding, null);

//            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
//                webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
//            }

        webView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return webView;
    } else {
        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(MainActivity.this);
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        final TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        textView.setTextSize(changedVolumeValue);

        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(data, new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                String imageAsStr = source.substring(source.indexOf(";base64,") + 8);
                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(imageAsStr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap imageAsBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);

                int imageWidthStartPx = (pxScreenWidth - imageAsBitmap.getWidth()) / 2;
                int imageWidthEndPx = pxScreenWidth - imageWidthStartPx;

                Drawable imageAsDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), imageAsBitmap);
                imageAsDrawable.setBounds(imageWidthStartPx, 0, imageWidthEndPx, imageAsBitmap.getHeight());
                return imageAsDrawable;
            }
        }, null));

        int pxPadding = dpToPx(12);

        textView.setPadding(pxPadding, pxPadding, pxPadding, pxPadding);

        scrollView.addView(textView);
        return scrollView;
    }
}

private void loseFocusOnSearchView() {
    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenuItem);
}

private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    return Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pageCount;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        currentPage = position;
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change textSize in `WebView` or in `TextView`?

Comment: both the views.

Answer (score 0):

There is an xml attribute you can use:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="200dp"
  app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

This was added in Android 8 but it is included in support library. Find more abojt it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html